# How to Terraform Create and Validate AWS Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am attempting to create and validate an AWS Certificate using Terraform by following the example from the Terraform documentation here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate_validation#dns-validation-with-route-53

My Terraform file looks like:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "vpn_server" {
  domain_name = "stuff.mine.com"
  
  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags = {
    Name = "certificate"
    Scope = "vpn_server"
    Environment = "vpn"
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "vpn_server" {
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.vpn_server.arn

  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.my_dns_record_vpn_server : record.fqdn]

  timeouts {
    create = "2m"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "my_dns" {
  name = "stuff.mine.com"

  tags = {
    name = "dns_zone"
  }
}


resource "aws_route53_record" "my_dns_record_vpn_server" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.vpn_server.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = resource.aws_route53_zone.my_dns.zone_id
}
```

The problem is that when running `terraform apply` the Validation always reaches the time-out and fails with the error messages:

```
aws_acm_certificate.vpn_server: Creating...
aws_acm_certificate.vpn_server: Creation complete after 8s [id=arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:320289993971:certificate/7e859491-141f-49d5-b50e-c44cf4e1db4e]
aws_route53_zone.my_dns: Creating...
aws_route53_zone.my_dns: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_route53_zone.my_dns: Creation complete after 52s [id=Z09112516IIP4OEAIIQ7]
aws_route53_record.my_dns_record_vpn_server["stuff.mine.com"]: Creating...
aws_route53_record.my_dns_record_vpn_server["stuff.mine.com"]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.my_dns_record_vpn_server["stuff.mine.com"]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.my_dns_record_vpn_server["stuff.mine.com"]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.my_dns_record_vpn_server["stuff.mine.com"]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.my_dns_record_vpn_server["stuff.mine.com"]: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
aws_route53_record.my_dns_record_vpn_server["stuff.mine.com"]: Creation complete after 58s [id=Z09112516IIP4OEAIIQ7__ebd2853fcbfc7cc8bd6582e65d940d54.stuff.mine.com._CNAME]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Creating...
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]
aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server: Still creating... [2m0s elapsed]

╷
│ Error: Error describing created certificate: Expected certificate to be issued but was in state PENDING_VALIDATION
│
│   with aws_acm_certificate_validation.vpn_server,
│   on main.tf line 61, in resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "vpn_server":
│   61: resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "vpn_server" {
│
╵
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing to get the Certificate Validation to complete?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, you can't just create a Route53 zone without having the domain name purchased somewhere and delegated to Route53 already. You're creating records in a DNS zone that isn't actually "hooked up to the Internet" yet, so the validation is never going to work. Also, in my experience even when you have it all setup right the validation can take up to 30 minutes, so setting a timeout limit of 2 minutes is almost guaranteed to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The domain validation records need to be in a public zone that is properly delegated. So if you owned `mine.com` and then wanted to create a zone called `stuff.mine.com` then you would need to set `NS` records in `mine.com` for `stuff.mine.com` that points to the `stuff.mine.com` zone's NS servers which you aren't doing here and aren't using an already configured zone.

Without that, the records will be created in your zone but that zone isn't then properly delegated and so nothing will ever be able to resolve those records. You should be able to test this by attempting to resolve them yourself or using an external resolver tool such as [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/).

There's probably a lot to consider here but you might want to set up a zone that will contain the eventual records you want to create (so the record pointing to the web server/load balancer that you want the certificate for plus the ACM domain validation records) separately and then just refer to the zone by using the [`aws_route53_zone` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/route53_zone) so your domain validation records are created there.

Comment: So the purpose of my certificates are only for use with AWS Client VPN, i.e `aws_ec2_client_vpn_endpoint` in Terraform. We don't be providing any public services within our VPC. As our certificates are only for the purpose of the private VPN, is there no way that we can do this with private DNS?

Comment: No because the ACM validator needs to resolve your records from a public facing endpoint. The [ACME protocol's DNS challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge) works similarly in that you need public facing records to validate that you own the zone. If it worked with private zones you'd be able to issue a certificate for a domain that you didn't own which defeats the point of the challenge. You can still issue certs for private usage (eg for an internal ALB) but the challenge records need to be in an equivalent public zone.

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) Terraform module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-acm) is designed specifically for this. From it's `ReadMe.md`:

```
Usage with Route53 DNS validation (recommended)
module "acm" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/acm/aws"
  version = "~> 4.0"

  domain_name  = "my-domain.com"
  zone_id      = "Z2ES7B9AZ6SHAE"

  subject_alternative_names = [
    "*.my-domain.com",
    "app.sub.my-domain.com",
  ]

  wait_for_validation = true

  tags = {
    Name = "my-domain.com"
  }
}
```